# What does reactive power translate to in terms of torque?

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

Say I'm trying to connect an AC generator to a circuit containing an inductor and a resistor, powered by a steam turbine.
I understand that because of the resistor, I'll be dissipating energy and therefore I'll need to drive the generator with a certain torque.
But what about the inductor? Obviously there's no dissipation of energy. Rather it is given and taken from the inductor. So does this mean that I'll get pulses of torque in the generator shaft? I mean, sometimes the inductor will pose a torque that opposes the rotation of the shaft, then the next moment it will produce a torque in the same direction. Have I understood this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my way own of looking at it. Your mileage may vary:

If the AC load contains inductance, then anytime the AC source voltage is increasing in magnitude, the inductor will "push back" and oppose the increase, and when the source voltage is decreasing, the inductor will "pull back" and oppose the decrease.

This means that the inductive part of the load is continuously "fighting against" the source, preventing it from delivering its full rated power to the remaining resistive portion of the load.

And it's worse than that: the power company charges you for fighting their source- you pay for the inductive power, which performs no useful work, as well as the resistive power.

Comment: Thank you. I was interested in particular about the torques on the shaft. What happens to them with reactive power?

Comment: I do not know, but suggest you post that question on the engineering stack exchange.